# Word Addin - open a file as a new document in office 365 online

Tags: office-js

I am using this code:

```
Word.run(function (context) {
    context.application.createDocument().open();
    return context.sync();
})
```

To open Word in Office 365 online, it is not working. I am getting this error:

> Sorry, this function isn’t available. Perform a run-time check on the Office add-in to find out whether the feature is supported by the host.

I am using the `https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/office.js`
version.

Is there any road map for availability of this in Word Online?

Answer (score 0):

This function is part of the proposed WordApi 1.4 spec and not yet included in the product. I don't have an ETA for when it might be available.

From the [documentation](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/tree/WordJs_1.4_OpenSpec):

> Note: The features listed are still in the design and review phase and are not yet available as part of the product. The final design is subject to change. When the feature is made available, the final specification will be published as part of the master repository.